# Where should i update a "transaction" model when having a OrderService and a TransactionService

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have two services:
An OrderService which has handy methods for working with orders.
And i have a TransactionService which has handy methods for working with payment transactions.

I want to update an orders status when a transaction has been paid. But i am not sure where to do this. It is, i think, neither the responsibility of the two services.

I can do something like this:

```
$this->orderService->updateOrderStatusUsingTransaction($order, $event->transaction);
```

But then i am making the orderService also responsible for updating the Transaction. While i only want it to be responsible for orders.

```
$this->transactionService->updateOrderStatusUsingTransaction($order, $event->transaction);
```

But then i am making the transactionService also responsible for updating the Transaction. While i only want that to be responsible for transactions.

```
/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param TransactionChanged $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(TransactionChanged $event) {
    /** @var Order $order */
    $order = $event->transaction->order()->first();
    /** @var User $customer */
    $customer = $order->customer()->first();

    $this->orderService->updateOrderStatusUsingTransaction($order, $event->transaction);
    $this->orderMailService->mailCustomerAboutCurrentOrderStatus($order, $customer);
}
```

I suspect i need an additional layer outside of these services to help me solve the problem. What would be some best practises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i've ended up doing was that i created a checkout service which coordinates communication between my orderService and TransactionService. For example instead of having this function signature:
`$this->orderService->updateOrderStatusUsingTransaction($order, $event->transaction);`
I've done something like this:
`$this->orderService->updateOrderStatus($order, $status);`

The checkout service is calling that function. But before it does it extracts the status from the transaction. And then is calls that function. So that the order service does not have to know about that transaction.